# Can I find a unitary matrix $U$ that commutes with a positive-definite matrix $A$ and $xU=Uy$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If I have [Hermitian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermitian_matrix) matrices $x,y\in$[$M_n(\mathbb{C})$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_ring) such that they have equal eigenvalues and both commute with a [positive-definite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definite_matrix) matrix $A\in{M_n(\mathbb{C})}$, then can I find a unitary matrix $U\in$[$U_n$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unitary_group) such that $xU=Uy$ and $UA=AU$?

It is easy to see that one can find a unitary matrix $U\in{U_n}$ such that $xU=Uy$ since they have equal eigenvalues and are both Hermitian. So my question is more about whether one can find one that also commutes with $A$. If not, then under what conditions would I need to put on $x$ and $y$ to get this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not always. Consider
$$
A=x=\pmatrix{1\\ &2}\quad\text{and}\quad y=\pmatrix{2\\ &1}.
$$
Since $A$ is a diagonal matrix with distinct diagonal elements, if $AU=UA$, then $U$ must be a diagonal matrix. Hence $U$ commutes with both $x$ and $y$. But then the equation $xU=Uy$ implies $(x-y)U=0$. Since $x-y$ is nonsingular, $U$ is necessarily zero.

Answer (score 1):

The crucial idea is from the simultaneous diagonalizing commuting diagonalizable matrices.

Let $\mathbb{C}^n=\oplus V_{\lambda}$ be the decomposition by eigenspaces of $A$. Then each $V_{\lambda}$ is stable under $x$ and $y$. To see this $w\in V_{\lambda}$ gives $Axw=xAw=x\lambda w=\lambda xw$, similarly for $y$.

Let $U_1$'s columns be the unit orthogonal eigenvectors of $x$ in each $V_{\lambda}$. Then $U_1^{-1} AU_1=D_1$ is diagonal. Also, $U_1^{-1}xU_1=D_x$ is diagonal.

Let $U_2$'s columns be the unit orthogonal eigenvectors of $y$ in each $V_{\lambda}$. Then $U_2^{-1} AU_2=D_1$ and $U_2^{-1}yU_2=D_y$ are diagonal. Here, $U_1$ and $U_2$ are unitary.

Suppose there is a **unitary** matrix $P$ such that
$(U_2P)^{-1}A  U_2P=D_1$ and $(U_2P)^{-1}y U_2P= P^{-1}D_y P=D_x$. This $P$ satisfies
$$P^{-1}D_1P=D_1, \ \  P^{-1}D_yP=D_x. (*)$$

Then take $U=U_1(U_2P)^{-1}$. Then we have $AU=UA$ and $xU=Uy$.

Conversely, assume there is a unitary $U$ such that $AU=UA$ and $xU=Uy$. Then $AUU_2=UAU_2=UU_2D_1$ and $xUU_2=UyU_2=UU_2D_y$. Thus,
$$
A=(UU_2)D_1(UU_2)^{-1}, \ \ x=(UU_2)D_y(UU_2)^{-1}.
$$
Apply $U_1^{-1}$ on the left and $U_1$ on the right, we obtain
$$
D_1=(U_1^{-1}UU_2 ) D_1(U_1^{-1}UU_2)^{-1}, \ \ D_x=(U_1^{-1}UU_2) D_y (U_1^{-1}UU_2)^{-1}.
$$
Thus, $P=(U_1^{-1}UU_2)^{-1}$ is a unitary matrix satisfying (*).

There is always a permutation matrix $P$ (and it is unitary) with $P^{-1} D_y P=D_x$ since $x$ and $y$ have the same set of eigenvalues. However, such a permutation (or unitary) matrix $P$ is not guaranteed to keep $D_1$ the same.

Consider the following example:
$$
A=D_1=\begin{pmatrix}2 & & \\ & 2 & \\ & & 3\end{pmatrix}, x=D_x=\begin{pmatrix}5 & & \\  & 7 & \\ & & 5\end{pmatrix}, 
y=D_y=\begin{pmatrix}5 & & \\ & 5 & \\ & & 7\end{pmatrix}
$$
To keep diagonals of $D_1$ in place, the unitary matrix $P$ is of the form
$$
P=\begin{pmatrix} P_2 & \\ & c \end{pmatrix}
$$
with $P_2$ is $2\times 2$ unitary and $|c|=1$. This $P$ is unable to swap $5$ and $7$ to get $D_x$. In fact,
$$
P^{-1}D_yP=D_y.
$$
Hence, for the above example, the unitary matrix $U$ with $AU=UA$ and $xU=Uy$ does not exist.

However, if we change $y$ to
$$
\begin{pmatrix}7 & & \\ & 5 & \\ & & 5\end{pmatrix},
$$
then such $U$ exists.

**Summary and Additional condition**

Let $U_1$ and $U_2$ be unitary with $U_1^{-1}AU_1=U_2^{-1}AU_2=D_1$ and $U_1^{-1}xU_1=D_x$, $U_2^{-1}yU_2=D_y$, such that $D_1$, $D_x$, $D_y$ are diagonal. The existence of such $U_1$ and $U_2$ are guaranteed.

Then some unitary $P$ satisfies (*)
$$
P^{-1}D_1P=D_1,  \ P^{-1}D_yP=D_x.
$$

This condition (*) is equivalent to:

$x$ and $y$ are similar (same multiset of eigenvalues) when restricted to each eigenspace $V_{\lambda}$ of $A$.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by the eigenvectors of $x$ in each $V_\lambda$?

Also, wouldn't it be easier to start with their [Schur decompositions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_decomposition)? So each $x,y,$ and $A$ would be $A=U_AD_AU_A^{-1}$, $x=U_xD_xU_x^{-1}$, and $y=U_yD_yU_y^{-1}$ for unitary matrices $U_A,U_x,U_y$ and diagonals $D_A,D_x,D_y$?

Comment: This is to find the same matrix $U_1$, that diagonalizes both $A$ and $x$ simultaneously. Similarly for $A$ and $y$.

Comment: Eigenvectors of $x$ in each $V_{\lambda}$ means, eigenvectors of $x:V_{\lambda}\rightarrow V_{\lambda}$.

Comment: I don't get it. If $A$ has eigenvectors $u_1,\ldots,u_n$, then what would the eigenvectors of $x$ and $y$ be in that sense?

Comment: Consider $x$ as a linear transformation on $V_{\lambda}$, the space of eigenvectors of $A$ whose corresponding eigenvalue is $\lambda$.

Comment: Wouldn't there be a permutation matrix somewhere, so that we can get equal diagonals? So, I first simultaneously diagonalize $A$ and $x$ (and I can do this since they commute), so then $U_1^{-1}AU_1=D_1$ and $U_1^{-1}xU_1=D_x$ for diagonals $D_1,D_x$ and unitary $U_1$. Similarly for $y$, $U_2^{-1}AU_2=D_2$ and $U_2^{-1}yU_2=D_y$ for unitary $U$ and diagonals $D_2,D_y$. So I would need to permute $D_y$ to get $D_x$? But then how do we know that permutation matrix will also permute $D_2$ to $D_1$?

Comment: I didn't think of permutation matrix was needed. It was a mistake. For A, I started with arranging eigenspaces, so at least $D_1=D_2$. but $D_x$ may be permited to be $D_y$. I will think about this more.

Comment: Yeah, something seems off about this to me. It seems like there needs to be some conditions on $x$ and $y$ for this to be true, maybe?

Comment: In the summary, did you mean to write that the existence of such $U_1$ and $U_2$ are **not** guaranteed?

Comment: Such $U_1$, $U_2$ are guaranteed, but existence of unitary $P$ with (*) is not.